# How set children position in canvas based on its width wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, canvas

Lets say canvas child has values left = 50, top = 50 when width of canvas = 500. When canvas is resizes how to set the left and top positions relative with the width of the canvas.

If user runs the application in big window or resizes the window, left and top positions of canvas children are messed up. How to rearrange the left and top positions of canvas children

Comment: We need a little more context. Are you using the canvas as some sort of drag-and-drop surface for the user to put things on, or are you trying to make a UI like a form? If you're going to make a standard app UI, using something like `Grid` or `StackPanel` is going to do a _much_ better job at layout.

Comment: Yes, here user will drag and drop controls to canvas dynamically, and user can move the controls inside the canvas. How to set left and top with relative to the canvas width

Comment: You need to update the Left and Top values according to the width. But  if you set the Width of the Canvas to 500, it won't change when you resize the window though so I don't really understand your issue?

Comment: Am able to get that, this canvas is inside a grid, here is my xaml <Border x:Name="designer" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Height="Auto">
                <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <canvas:QuestionDesignerCanvas x:Name="canvasDesigner"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>

Comment: on this event Designer.SizeChanged+=, am getting this designer width and assigning to canvas. As canvas is inside this border control. On this am calculating the width and height and want to update the child controls

Comment: So what is your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are just putting your elements on the window and then giving them margins, they won't scale with the window. I recommend keeping them inside a `Grid` element, which automatically scales its contents. Then give your row/column definitions that allow the contents to scale. For example:

`<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />` will resize to fit the contents and no more,

and `<RowDefinition Height="*" />` will take up all remaining space.

Edit: Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx) for more information. You might have to play around with the xaml code.

Comment: I have canvas here, were user will add children dynamically and move them in the canvas. Its like free form, where user will arrange the controls

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom canvas with override OnPropertyChanged like this:

```
 public class YourCustomCanvas : Canvas
{
    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
        var ep = e.Property;
        if (ep != null)
        {
            if(ep.Name == "Left")
            foreach (FrameworkElement child in Children)
              SetLeft(child, GetLeft(child) / (double)e.OldValue * (double)e.NewValue);
            else if (ep.Name == "Top")
                foreach (FrameworkElement child in Children)
                    SetTop(child, GetTop(child) / (double)e.OldValue * (double)e.NewValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use YourCustomCanvas istead of the Canvas in your project like this:

```
// Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
YourCustomCanvas canvas = new YourCustomCanvas();
```

Answer (score 0):

I will provide a recommendation, but because the question gives us nothing to work with in terms of existing code, I can't provide any specific/complete code until the question is updated.

A drag-and-drop interface, if done properly with the MVVM pattern, probably involves an `ItemsControl` (or something derived from it) whose `ItemsPanelTemplate` is a `Canvas`. Bindings will have to provide the `Left` and `Top` placements, probably as a percentage of the canvas dimensions, e.g.

```
...
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        ...
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RelativePositionConverter}">
                    <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                        <Binding Path="Left" />
                        <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}" />
                    </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RelativePositionConverter}">
                    <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                        <Binding Path="Top" />
                        <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}" />
                    </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        ...
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
...
```

You will then need to create a class implementing `IMultiValueConverter` (the `StaticResource` I happened to call `RelativePositionConverter` in that XAML) that takes multiplies the first value (relative position; double value between 0 and 1) by the second value (the width or height of the canvas) to get the correct position. Note that you can't really implement the `ConvertBack`, so the code for your `Thumb` to enable the drag functionality is going to have to do similar math to set the backing value.

There are a lot of moving parts to accomplish this, but I think I have provided enough information to get you on the right path. If you have further questions on how to do bindings, converters, thumbs, control templating, etc., it would probably be best to create a new question with more specific information.

Comment: I am not implementing this way, I override the canvas and on resize event trying to update the canvas left and top , based on the width of the canvas. Using newCanvasLeft = (oldleft * new Width)/oldWidth, this is not working correctly, Is my approach is correct?

Comment: or I have to use MeasureOverride() or ArrangeOverride() methods?

Comment: @GANI, I'm sorry, but you're only giving me tiny fragments of your code. It's going to be difficult or impossible to help. I suppose you could loop through and try to adjust the placement of all child items on resize, but... I really can't recommend doing it that way.